# Should I use game engine for android

Tags: android

I am wondering, if I am to make a simple basic bird shooting game (birds flying above and boy shooting them from bottom), then do I require a game engine for android develpment? Should I go through the hassle of learning AndEngine? Or Do I do it using SurfaceView/ or even animations?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think learning to use an engine is a hassle? Do you know OpenGL ES enough to start straight ahead? Canvas? How to design a game in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to have AndEngine. Its better than SurfaceView since AndEngine is a Game Engine. Here it comes all types of Animation and Its easy for you have better game experience but we have to take care of Memory Issues here.

You can try to use Cocos2D also. List of opensource game Engine are [GameEngines](http://ntt.cc/2011/05/08/8-open-source-android-game-engines.html). Try to think in all the way to suitable for your game.

[Tutorial for Cocos2d](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/)

[AndEngine Tutorial](http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/)

Comment: So you recommend using a game engine over Surfaceview even for simple games

Answer (score 2):

You could try out [Google's new games engine](https://developers.google.com/playn/) for android.

It's pretty new and I don't know if any existing games utilise it, but it's in active development and new features are coming out frequently. Including the recent feature to export to IOS, making it an option for cross-platform deployment.

Comment: It is a good one but fairly new engine. My question was not about alternative but when to use it. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [list of Game engines](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=21471.0) but mostly for larger-scale production games. There's an "Open Source" listing at the bottom too.

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking for list of game engines. My question was whether to use a a game engine or not

Answer (score 0):

Another new cross-platform Lua-based engine to try is BatteryTech Engine.  http://www.batterytechsdk.com

Free to Try
Supports Android, iOS, BB10, PC, Mac

License purchase gives you full source code.